# Select rows which do not have the first column matching any other rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select the rows that do not have the first column matching. For example, from the data below;

```
Person            | Room
---------------------------------------
ben               | 1
jake              | 3
jake              | 1
steven            | 2
james             | 1
james             | 2
james             | 3
```

The query would only return these rows:

```
Person            | Room
---------------------------------------
ben               | 1
jake              | 3
steven            | 2
james             | 1
```

It doesn't matter what value the room column returns.
And it needs to be able to work with increasing room numbers and different names.

I've had no look searching for a answer and can't figure out how to do it, however it might be my current mindset and it might be really easy to do.

Comment: Do you have others columns with auto_increment or timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Person, MIN(Room) AS Room
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Person
```

And if you can guarantee that the [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) setting will always be turned off, the following is also possible in MySql:

```
SELECT Person, Room
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Person
```

But I'd use the `MIN()` function just to be safe...